# Jquery Waypoints basic script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

i've copied a very basic script from the Jquery Waypoints website,
all i want it to do at the moment, is when #header reaches the top of the viewpoint, an alert would pop up.

i've loaded the scripts in this order

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="waypoints/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jscript.min.js">      </script>
```

And this is the element that i want to have the waypoint (#header)

```
<div id="header">
<h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

This is the CSS for #header, which is probably not needed for this question

```
#header {
height:75px;
width:auto;
position:absolute;
background:#212121;
top:50px;
left:200px;
right:100px;
}
```

And then the very simple jQuery script, which is the same script (with a different element name) from the site http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

```
$('#header').waypoint(function() {
  alert('Top of header hit top of viewport.');
});
```

When i check it on chrome, and scroll past the header, no alert comes up, and no errors are shown in the console.
Please help me to understand my mistakes here,
Thanks.

Comment: that is because, header is already at the top of viewport.

Comment: it is 50px from the top, and i have text that i scroll down so that the header is then at the top.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get it to work by adding a document ready function

so the script would now look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#header').waypoint(function() {
    alert('Top of header hit top of viewport.');
});
});
```